# What is the difference between the .Kdb file, the .jks file, and the CMS file?

Tags: ssl, keystore, mq, jks

When I connect to the Remote Queue Manager, which is configured with SSL, using C# code

- What is the difference between the .Kdb file, the .jks file, and the CMS file?
- Do I need to point the .kdb file (or) the .jks file to the `MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

CMS is a type of keystore, and that keystore will have the extension .kdb
JKS is an alternate type of keystore, used with Java, and has the extension .jks

Your .NET code should be using a CMS .kdb file.